# If autocommit is false in postgres will transaction be automatically roll backed

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions

I am pretty new to model layer just need clarification that in our code if autocommit is false like

```
Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection(userDb);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

And we get an exception which is not related to postgres like

```
if (response.getValue() != null) {   
    conn.commit();
}
```

Where response object is arbitrary value,does the transaction be roll backed automatically in postgres.

Thanks

Comment: If nobody commits the transaction, then at the end of the session it will be rolled back. So the answer is `yes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If a connection is closed, the transaction should be rolled back by the database. If you're using a connection pool, the transaction should be rolled back by the pool, when the connection is returned.

However this can depend on the driver, as well as the connection pool, so you should explicitly do commits and rollbacks instead of relying on the driver or the pool.

Comment: In both cases as you said either database or pool is handling this, then y we need to do this explicitly, is the process different if we do this explicitly.

Comment: @Nareshkumar Well, for example (old) versions of the Oracle JDBC driver did a commit when you closed the connection without an explicit commit or rollback (I believe they fixed that as, iirc, JDBC now explicitly requires a rollback now). However it is still better to be explicit (if only to avoid weird problems if you use a connection pool (or driver) that doesn't behave.

Answer (score 1):

For be sure, better rollback transaction explicitly:

```
if (response.getValue() != null) {   
    conn.commit();
}
else {
    conn.rollback();
}
```